# Delete code not working with connecting button

Tags: php

On the page I am trying to have the delete button on an update form with other edit functionality, and in all attempts it seems my delete messes with this.

This is the link to the site so you can test: http://exhibitjewellery.com/editstocktest.php
(the button is currently under 'all pieces in series' and clicking a name opens the form as a collapsible panel)

I have used the dreaweaver cs5 wizard if that help getting an idea of how the rest of my code looks. Can you help me?

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
echo 'Do you really want to delete ' . $_GET['delete'] . '? <a  href="editstock.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['delete'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="editstock.php">No</a>';
exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM pieces WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: editstock.php"); 
exit();
}
?>
```

The above code to be activated by this button:

```
<input name="delete" type="button" id="delete" value="delete" style="width:20%; float:right"/>
```

Comment: Where are you getting `$_POST['id']` from? It doesn't appear anywhere in your code here as a POST variable, or as a GET variable.

Comment: I'll get to this before someone else does: don't use mysql for new projects because it's deprecated. Use **mysqli** or PDO.

Comment: well i have tried to combine dreamweaver wizard code with another o i can get the confirm page and that is just how it was so to be honest i dont totally understand. all i really want is a delete button with a confirm page. a delete button i can copy and past to other tables without changing code would be great aswell (a global?) but i dont think this is possible...

Comment: how do i change to mysqli?

Comment: PHP's mysql extension will be removed soon. Mysqli replaces it. You can find the reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). It's very similar to mysql, but provides better support for more recent facilities in MySQL.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="delete" style="width:20%; float:right"/>
</form>
```

or

```
<input name="delete" type="button" id="delete" value="delete" style="width:20%; float:right" onclick="window.location.href = '?delete=delete'" />
```

Comment: so that code i good that it link to the confirm but then i recieved this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function GetSQLValueString() in D:\Hosting\11204618\html\editstock.php on line 11

Comment: This doesn't address basic problem here: the item id isn't being passed to the query that does the delete.

Comment: yes i know...will it work if i replace the POST with GET on that line? when you said it doesnt need the get/post im not sure i understand why because isnt that how it carries the 'id' to the confirm page? ah! confused!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your source code in http://exhibitjewellery.com/editstocktest.php you will see that your form is using `method="post"`

```
<form action="/editstocktest.php?" method="post" name="form4" id="form4">
```

so you can't us `$_GET` -

```
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {}
```

also, in your delete link, you are using the value of `delete`, but I think you want `id` -`$_POST['id']`

finally, when you click on that link `$_POST['id']` is no long accessible to use inside the `if (isset($_GET['yesdelete']))`, so you need to add the `id` to the url

---

**edit 1**
here is one suggested way to change it, although it is never really a good idea to delete based off a url. It would be good to make sure that only an admin can access / delete this way. Note, `GetSQLValueString()` is a Dreamweaver created function, so you need to make sure to include the file where that is defined.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
echo 'Do you really want to delete ' . $_POST['piece'] . '? <a  href="editstock.php?yesdelete=' . $_POST['id'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="editstock.php">No</a>';
exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
include('file where GetSQLValueString() is defined'); // you have to change **file where GetSQLValueString() is defined** to the file path
$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM pieces WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1",
                   GetSQLValueString($_GET['yesdelete'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: editstock.php"); 
exit();
}
?>
```

---

**edit #2**
Since you want to use `onclick` to perform the delete function, you will need to modify your `location.href` and use `$_GET`.

your html button

```
<input name="delete" type="button" id="delete" value="delete" style="width:20%; float:right" onclick="window.location.href = '?delete=delete&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&piece=<?php echo $row['piece']; ?>'"/>
```

I don't know how you are populating your form elements, so change `$row['id']` & `$row['piece']` to your method.

then your delete function -

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
echo 'Do you really want to delete ' . $_GET['piece'] . '? <a  href="editstock.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['id'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="editstock.php">No</a>';
exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
include('file where GetSQLValueString() is defined'); // you have to change **file where GetSQLValueString() is defined** to the file path
$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM pieces WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1",
                   GetSQLValueString($_GET['yesdelete'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: editstock.php"); 
exit();
}
?>
```

**edit 3**
if you can't find where dreamweaver is defining the function, you can redeclare it -

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
echo 'Do you really want to delete ' . $_GET['piece'] . '? <a  href="editstock.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['id'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="editstock.php">No</a>';
exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {

// redefine if does not exist
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType,
$theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
$theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
}

$theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ?
mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

switch ($theType) {
case "text":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;    
case "long":
case "int":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "double":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
break;
case "date":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
break;
case "defined":
$theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
break;
}
return $theValue;
}
}


$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM pieces WHERE id='%s' LIMIT 1",
                   GetSQLValueString($_GET['yesdelete'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_connectmysql, $connectmysql);
$Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $connectmysql) or die(mysql_error());
header("location: editstock.php"); 
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: so if i understand this what i do: change all GET to POST then where is the url do i add id? sorry and thankyou...

Comment: super! and to make the button work is this right: <input name="delete" type="button" id="$_POST['id']" value="delete" style="width:20%; float:right" onclick="window.location.href = '?delete=delete'"/>

Comment: Well if you are using `onclick` to submit the change, then you do need to use `$_GET`. I will update again, give me a minute.

Comment: these are the three error msgs that appear!

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'file where GetSQLValueString() is defined' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in D:\Hosting\11204618\html\editstock.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to undefined function GetSQLValueString() in D:\Hosting\11204618\html\editstock.php on line 1

Comment: Please re-read my answer - `Note, GetSQLValueString() is a Dreamweaver created function, so you need to make sure to include the file where that is defined.` and `include('file where GetSQLValueString() is defined'); // you have to change **file where GetSQLValueString() is defined** to the file path`. Dreamweaver creates the `GetSQLValueString()` function. I can't see your files, so I don't know where it is defined, only you can know that. If not, you will need to redefine it.

Comment: wow...is this entire thing flawed? how much trouble will dreamweaver specific functions get me in later?

Comment: and are you referring to the basic connection include? i cant see what else it may be? i think im melting...

Comment: Whether it is dreamweaver created, or user created, you just need to know where the function is defined, and make sure to include it. If you don't know where it is, you can look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8990365/689579 - it has `if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) { ... }` which you can copy.

Comment: so: include("GetSQLValueString"); or: include('if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")');

Comment: no, it should be a file path - `include('dw_funtions.php');` or `include('includes.php');`. OR you can copy the code from http://stackoverflow.com/q/8990365/689579 and redefine it if it does not exist. See my **edit 3**. You can also look at the `basic connection include` as it might be in there.

Comment: ok! i just put it in the main php block which orted that out and it works! i cant thank you enough for your time and patience...its embarasing how much i have struggled with this!

Comment: hi! i have tried to transfer the same we organised here to a new button and its not working with the second in taking the id and am not sure why...

Comment: Without seeing code I don't know how to help. I showed the example of this `onclick="window.location.href = '?delete=delete&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&piece=<?php echo $row['piece']; ?>'"` You need to change the `$row[]` variables with how you set your item id and piece

Answer (score -1):

I know it sounds like a stupid question, but are you using a HTML form? Also, you might want to make the input type "submit" rather than "button"

aka

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="delete" style="width:20%; float:right"/>
</form>
```

Comment: its a php fueled update form that i am trying to add the button too so that it act separately form the submit 'update' button. it seemed to mess everything up when i had two ubmits next to eachother which i why i just want the delete to be a link

Comment: This doesn't address basic problem here: the item id isn't being passed to the query that does the delete.